# Laravel 7 Eloquent: Comment BelongsTo User belongsToMany Groups

Tags: laravel, eloquent, has-many, has-and-belongs-to-many

I am trying to setup the following relationsship:

Comment (user_id) `->belongTo` User `->belongsToMany` ->Groups

(Pivot: group_user)

I want to be able to fetch all groups associated with the comment with: `Comment::find(i)->groups`.
Also `Comment::wherehas('groups')` and `Comment::Where(groups in [1,3])`

I've been looking at https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep#belongsto
But can't get it to work as intended.

```
 public function groups()
    {

         return $this->hasManyDeep('App\Group', ['group_user', 'App\User']);
    }
```

Laravel 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From github discussion:

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentHasManyDeep\HasRelationships;

    public function groups()
    {
        return $this->hasManyDeep(
            Group::class
            [User::class, 'group_user'],
            ['id'],
            ['user_id']
        );
    }
}
```

Works like a charm!

Answer (score -1):

This may help you

```
//'tables1','tables2','tables3' are relations in USER model & 'COL 7' is column of table 3

$x=USER::where('status','active')->with('tables1','tables2','tables3')->whereHas('tables3', function($q)
                {
                    $q->where('COL 7',"US");

                })->get();
                dd($x);
```